# Drawing row background in QTableView in Qt5 is not possible anymore?

Tags: qt5, qtableview

with the following code we used to set the background color of a row in a QTableView when hovering over it:

```
void StableTable::mouseMoveEvent ( QMouseEvent * event ) {
    int row = rowAt ( event->y() );
    if( row == -1 ) return;
    if ( row == mHoveredRow ) return;

    QBrush background(palette().midlight());
    QColor backColor = background.color();
    background.setColor(backColor);

    for (int col = 0; col < model()->columnCount(); col++) {
        QModelIndex inn = model()->index(row, col);
        model()->setData(inn, background, Qt::BackgroundRole);

        if( mHoveredRow != -1 ) {
            QModelIndex prevInn = model()->index(mHoveredRow, col);
            model()->setData(prevInn, palette().base(), Qt::BackgroundRole);
        }
    }
    mHoveredRow = row;  
}
```

It worked fine with Qt4.8.x but now with Qt5.4 no background color ist set anymore. Does anyone has clue if something has changed here?

Answer (score 0):

They changed some things around in Qt5. BackgroundRole is still available, but you have to wrap it in a QVariant. Here is how I set my background color in table widget items.

```
tableItem->setData(Qt::BackgroundRole, QVariant(QColor(Qt::yellow)));
```